# Wide Logo on start Screen in window store app?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In my app I want set set my default logo as wide logo.When user pin to start my app wide logo will be shown how to do that?
I tried to edit manifest file but every thing is fine there

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
      <Identity Name="eaccc03b-ad21-4762-9c73-39835d6eb23b" Publisher="CN=Admin" Version="1.0.0.0" />
      <Properties>
        <DisplayName>App5</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>Admin</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
      </Properties>
      <Prerequisites>
        <OSMinVersion>6.3.0</OSMinVersion>
        <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
      </Prerequisites>
      <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
      </Resources>
      <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="App5.App">
          <m2:VisualElements DisplayName="Kids" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="App5" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
            <m2:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png">
              <m2:ShowNameOnTiles>
                <m2:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
              </m2:ShowNameOnTiles>
            </m2:DefaultTile>
            <m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" />
            <m2:InitialRotationPreference>
              <m2:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
            </m2:InitialRotationPreference>
          </m2:VisualElements>
        </Application>
      </Applications>
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
      </Capabilities>
    </Package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add DefaultSize property：

```
<m2:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" DefaultSize="wide310x150Logo">
...
</m2:DefaultTile>
```

this will make the Wide Tile as Default tile. if you want the 150*150 logo as default,just change DefaultSize as `DefaultSize="square150x150Logo"`